# Express response payload on response finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express.JS server with many `res.json`. To perform statistics, logging and debugging, I want to capture the response payload in a catch-all hook.

I have found the `finish` event `res.on('finish')` but I cannot find how to extract the response payload from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

res.on('finish') is called once the data has been sent, so the payload doesn't necessarily exist on the server any more. You can add middleware to express to intercept every request and then override the `.json` method to log the data as the function is called:

```
router.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  var old = res.json.bind(res);
  res.json = (body) => {
    //Do whatever
    old(body);
  }
  next();
})
```

Comment: so what kind of middleware/event type subscription can I use to intercept response (error or ok) just before forwarding the response to client? Ideally just after res.send(data);

Answer (score 0):

Express response object is extending native http server of the Nodejs

You can see in the [link](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L43) exact place where it is extending

And if you look at the official documentation of Nodejs you can see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#event-finish_1) that http server is listening on some events like connect, close and finish